# Implementing common subexpression elimination

Tags: compiler-optimization, graph-algorithm, compiler-theory

I am looking into implementing common subexpression elimination (CSE) for expression graphs corresponding to large mathematical expressions (millions of nodes).

What algorithms are suitable for performing this? I was searching the internet for an easy-to-implement algorithm but I could not find anything. If possible the algorithm should have a linear complexity in the number of nodes of the complete expression graph.

Comment: This representation might help: http://www.masonchang.com/blog/2010/8/9/sea-of-nodes-compilation-approach.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are expressions with no side effects? Then the easiest thing to do is to hash the trees for each sub-expression into buckets to determine candidates for sub-expression elimination.
This is a special case of [CSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) where all the expressions are in a single (huge) "basic block".  (I use this idea as the basis for detecting [duplicate code](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/CloneDR).)

If the expressions have order and side effects, you may want to consider [Value Numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_value_numbering).

Comment: Right, there are no side effects. If I understand your suggestion correctly, I should loop over the nodes of the expression, in the order of dependencies, and at each step check if an expression is already present in a hash map. If it is present, then use this subexpression instead, if not add it to the hash map. Is this correctly understood?

Comment: Yep. "In the order of dependencies" means bottom up for each tree.

Comment: I was actually thinking about this strategy. What kind of hashing would you use?

Comment: Doesn't matter much.  You want a hash function that maps most trees evenly across bins.  If you can build a raw hash function (something that produce 32 or 64 bits of hash value) on a single leaf node, you can compose hashes from children to get a parent hash code by simply adding/xoring the hashes of the children.  Then the hash code is simply that hash value modulo the number of buckets in your hashmap.